# how to add numbering inside the for loop?

Tags: python

I have a problem printing the line with the number. How to add numbering before of line? I made a comment on which part.

```
f = open('filename', "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    synonyms = []
    print(line) # I want my interface to be, 1. word 2. word, and so on
    answer = input("Answer: ").lower()
    for syn in wordnet.synsets(line.strip()):
        for l in syn.lemmas():
            synonyms.append(l.name())
```

My code is just printing

word1

Answer:

word2

Answer:

My ideal code is:

1.word1

Answer:

2.word2

Answer:

Answer (score 1):

replace your loop:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    print(str(i + 1) + '. ' + str(line))
```

"i" will be the number waited...

you could use string interpolation if you are at min python3.6

```
   print(f'{i + 1}. {line}')
```

Comment: where should i put it? under the for loop?

Comment: @AbbieB No, you should change your existing for loop to use `enumerate()` as illustrated here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of traversing through every line in the `lines` list, just go through the indexes of every element, and then print the `index+1`, as obviously list indexes start from 0, but we want our numbering to start from 1. So, instead of printing only the line, we'll print `line_no: line`

```py
f = open('filename', "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line_no in range(len(lines)):
    synonyms = []
    print(f"{line_no+1}: {lines[line_no]}") # I want my interface to be, 1. word 2. word, and so on
    answer = input("Answer: ").lower()
    for syn in wordnet.synsets(line.strip()):
        for l in syn.lemmas():
            synonyms.append(l.name())
```

Hope my answer helped :D

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable called `count` and increment it with each iteration of the `for` loop.
Code:

```py
count = 1
f = open('filename', "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    synonyms = []
    print(str(count) + ". " + line)
    count += 1
    answer = input("Answer: ").lower()
    for syn in wordnet.synsets(line.strip()):
        for l in syn.lemmas():
            synonyms.append(l.name())
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
f = open('filename', "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line_no,line in enumerate(lines):
    synonyms = []
    print(str(line_no+1)+'.'+line) # I want my interface to be, 1. word 2. word, and so on
    answer = input("Answer: ").lower()
    for syn in wordnet.synsets(line.strip()):
        for l in syn.lemmas():
            synonyms.append(l.name())
```